# Upload files in the background to Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, upload, background-process

I want my users to be able to start uploading a file on my web page, and for the upload to continue until completion even if the user exits the page.

Currently, the upload stops when the user goes to another page. How can I make sure that the upload continues in the background?